# How can I update a detached entity in EF CF multi-tier application?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, updating

I'm developing a multi-tier app using EF CF . I managed to delete a detached entity this way:

```
       public void Delete(DbSet MySet, object Obj)
        {
            MySet.Attach(Obj);
            var Entry = this.Entry(Obj);
            Entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
            this.SaveChanges();
        }
```

This method is defined in a class I called Adapter:DbContext.
The thing is, when updating, similar code doesn't work:

```
 public void Update(DbSet MySet, object Obj)             
    {
        MySet.Attach(Obj);
        var Entry = this.Entry(Obj);
        Entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        this.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This does not update the database nor throw any exceptions
How should I update a detached entity?

Comment: I think that: Entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(Obj); is redundant (you're setting your Obj entity to match your Obj entity) - however it looks like it should work.  What isn't working? Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: Worse... It does nothing >.< 
Btw thanks, I thought it had to be a redundancy.. (but again, it doesn't work either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of attaching the object, try retrieving the object and updating it - Note: I'm assuming your Id is Obj.Id

```
public void Update(DbSet MySet, object Obj)             
    {
        var objToUpdate = MySet.Find(Obj.Id);
        if (objToUpdate != null)
        {
        var Entry = this.Entry(objToUpdate );
        Entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(Obj)
        Entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        this.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works just fine, the error was somewhere else.
Sorry for the premature question!
I not deleting anyways since its kind of useful